# false returned when comparing 2 identically looking strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I use  Node.js script for scraping and I noticed that one of the strings scraped simply don't pass the regex.Regex isn't important here, but the string which acts strange, here's the example:

```
var scrapedData = '1111 test1'
var myData = '1111 test1'
scrapedData === myData

false
```

Now, If manually remove space between 1111 and test1 inside scrapedData, and then enter space, everything is ok.

```
var scrapedData = '1111 test1' // manually deleted and then added space
var myData = '1111 test1'
scrapedData === myData

true
```

So I guess `scrapedData` contains some hidden character that breaks my regex, it might have to do with encoding(utf-8 is used) ? Could it be replaced with single space character `' '` ?

Comment: The title is absurd. As you also point out, the strings aren't identical. There may be control characters for which you could and should check in the regex.

Comment: So *check* if it's really a space: `console.log(scrapedData.charCodeAt(4));`

Comment: You could use `scrapedData.charCodeAt(i)` to check what characters are inside the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this helps:

try using escape to see the actual char. for example:

```
escape('1111 test1')
```

should return  "1111%20test1" if the char is really a space.

Comment: I think [*encodeURIComponent*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.3.4) is preferred to *encode*.

Comment: Great! scraped data returned "1111%A0test1" while myData "1111%20test1".So what is this %A0 character ?

Comment: I fixed the problem finally with this str.replace(/\s+/g, " ");

Comment: %A0 is the non-breaking space while %20 is the space.